# dynamically change error div based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my error message depending on how many digits the user enters in credit card field. I'm trying to generate the message variable with this:

```
let numberDigit;
let creditCardMessage;

 if ($cardNumber.val().length < 13) {
   numberDigit = 'Too few digits. ';
 } else if ($cardNumber.val().length > 16) {
  numberDigit = 'Too many digits. ';
 }
creditCardMessage = numberDigit + 'Please enter between 13 and 16';
```

Then I want to pass the creditCardMessage variable in the following function:

```
function creditCardNumberEvent () {

if (!isCreditCardValid()) {
 showErrorMessage ($cardNumber, creditCardMessage, $cardNumber, 'creditCardError');
} else {
 removeErrorMessage($cardNumber, '#creditCardError');
}
}
```

All I get is the first value - the "too few digits." Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When running your script, you can call `CardNumberValid()` which returns a Boolean, meaning you can use it in an `if` statement, like `if(CardNumberValid())`

```js
function CardNumberValid() {
  var valid = true;
  var CardNumber = $("#CardNumber");
  if (CardNumber.val().length < 13) {
    $("#ErrorMsg").text("Too few digits. Please enter between 13 and 16");
    valid = false;
  } else if (CardNumber.val().length > 16) {
    $("#ErrorMsg").text("Too many digits. Please enter between 13 and 16");
    valid = false;
  }
  if(valid){
    $("#ErrorMsg").text("");
  }
  return valid;
}

$('#Validate').click(function() {
  alert("The card number " + (CardNumberValid() ? "is" : "is not") + " valid.");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="CardNumber" />
<div id="ErrorMsg" style="color:red;"></div>
<button id="Validate" type="button">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks KatoFett! Trying this. I'm not sure how I will pass the function instead of the variable?

Comment: The function simply returns a Boolean. If the credit card number is valid, the function will return `true`. Otherwise, it will return `false`. This can be used in an if statement like `if(CardNumberValid()) { alert("Credit Card is valid!"); }`

Answer (score 0):

I did figure this out. I created a function as suggested and passed that function as an argument in another function: (which I now know is a callback function)

```
function creditCardMessageFunction () {

let numberDigit;
let creditCardMessage;

  if ($cardNumber.val().length < 13) {
     numberDigit = 'Too few digits. ';
  } else if ($cardNumber.val().length > 16) {
     numberDigit = 'Too many digits. ';
  } else {
    numberDigit = 'Numeric Values Only. ';
}
creditCardMessage = numberDigit + 'Please enter numbers between 13 and 16.';
return creditCardMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```js
function logValidationMessage() {
  var cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardNumber');

  var numberDigits = null;

  if (cardNumber.value.length < 13) {
    numberDigits = 'Too few digits. ';
  } else if (cardNumber.value.length > 16) {
    numberDigits = 'Too many digits. ';
  } else {
    numberDigits = 'Card number is valid.';
  }

  console.log(numberDigits);
}

document.getElementById('btnCheckCardNumber').addEventListener('click', logValidationMessage);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cardNumber" />
<input type="button" id="btnCheckCardNumber" value="Check" />
```